# What will happen to Hanuman and the other Chiranjivis after the end of the Kali Yuga?

Tags: hanuman, yuga, kali-yuga, chiranjivi

Is there any reference regarding this in any Veda or other books?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do the eight immortals (Including Lord Hanuman) still exist in Kaliyuga?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18225/do-the-eight-immortals-including-lord-hanuman-still-exist-in-kaliyuga)

Answer (score 6):

**Who are Chiranjivis?**

> अश्वत्थामा बलिव्र्यासो हनूमांश्च विभीषण:। कृप: परशुरामश्च सप्तएतै चिरजीविन:॥
> सप्तैतान् संस्मरेन्नित्यं मार्कण्डेयमथाष्टमम्। जीवेद्वर्षशतं सोपि सर्वव्याधिविवर्जित॥

8 Chiranjivis (immortals) are : Ashwatthama, King Bali, Krishna Dvaipāyana (Vedvayasa of 28th Dwapara Yuga), Hanuman, Vibhishan, Kripacharya, Parashurama and Markandaya.

**Note:** This list is highly disputed. Few sources only consider 7 Chiranjivis  and few consider others as well (like Kak Bhusundi).

**Ashwatthama, Krishna Dvaipāyana, Kripacharya and Parashurama**

Will become one of the Saptrishis in 8th Manvantara. - [Vishnu Purana](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp076.htm)

Note: Ashwatthama is also mentioned as Ved Vayasa in 29th Dwapara Yuga as well ([Source](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp077.htm)). And Parashurama is Lord Vishnu's incarnation.

**King Bali**

Will hold the title of Indra (yes Indra is a post) in 8th Manavantara by the grace of Lord Vishnu. - [Vishnu Purana](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp076.htm)

**Hanumana and Vibhishan**

Will be living on earth till Lord Rama's history remains current. - [Valmiki Ramayana: Uttarakhand](http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/src-vrm:ram7-121)

---

Related

[Do the eight immortals (Including Lord Hanuman) still exist in Kaliyuga?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18225/do-the-eight-immortals-including-lord-hanuman-still-exist-in-kaliyuga/44733#44733)