# When do 'Chiranjeevi's die?

Tags: puranas, death

Hindus believe in a cyclic nature of time. Here the same key events are repeated forever. Then we should have the same 'Chiranjeevi's born repeatedly. This means, we should have an infinite number of them now. Else, they should die at some point of time. When and how does this death happen?

Comment: Partially Related https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/22680/12304

Comment: Usually the Chiranjeevis are given life till the end of the Kalpa. At the end of the Kalpa everything merges into the Cosmic Form and hence barring a few exceptions like Sanat Kumaras, etc. chiranjeevis lose their mortal body and merge into the Supreme to be reborn again in the next Kalpa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chiranjeevis live for one Kalpa, as described in [this chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp066.htm) of the Vishnu Purana:

> By immortality is meant existence to the end of the Kalpa: life as long as the three regions (earth, sky, and heaven) last is called exemption from (reiterated) death. The consequences of acts of iniquity or piety, such as Brahmanicide or an Aśwamedha, endure for a similar period, or until the end of a Kalpa, when all within the interval between Dhruva and the earth is destroyed.

But there are some exceptions to that.  For instance, Agastya has been blessed with a significantly longer life as I discuss [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/9276/36).  Also, more generally the inhabitants of Maharloka survive the end of the Kalpa; see my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2876/36).  But at least the standard kind of Chiranjeevi, who lives within the three worlds, perishes along with the three worlds at the end of the Kalpa.

Comment: What about Lord Hanuman?

Comment: Hanuman might become Brahma @Swapnil as discussed in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/50579/17833)