# What are the different ways to become immortal?

Tags: immortality, chiranjivi

What are the different ways to become immortal ? -
I think one way is to get access to the Amrita (which is perhaps kept in heaven(correct me if I am wrong)) and drink it.
What are the other ways ?

Note - By drinking Amrit (or I think any other means) one can become [immortal only for one day of Brahma](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/23740/23709) , not forever.

Comment: The Self (ātman) is already immortal, as for the body, it is perishable by its nature, it cannot be immortal. Pursuing immortality of body, is a vain quest by the ignorant. Because the one who knows about the Self, don't pursue immortality anymore,  they have realized that they are already immortal. It is ātman that is eternal and not the body.